# Load Knockout observableArray with server Json populate only one element

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js

here I am  developing an application that retrieve data in a server via jquery ajax with then I do the Databindings with knockout
The data json well pass to  my scripts the only the problem is that in my html table only one record  appears
here my json as given by the server:

Json returned by the server:

```
{
    "Id": "4 ",
    " key_0 ": " 4 ",
    " Nom_Agent ": " Grace ",
    " key_1 ": " Grace ",
    " PNom_Agent ": " Malulu ",
    " key_2 ": " Malulu "
    " Sexe_Agent ",
    " M ",
    " key_3 ",
    " M ",
    " Adresse_Agent ",
    " 2 ",
    " key_4 ",
    " 2 ",
    " Telephone_Agent ": " 243 900 100 115 ",
    " key_5 ": " 243 900 100 115 "
    " Libelle_Role ": " Cashier ",
    " key_6 ": " Cashier ",
    " Email_Agent ": " gracemalulu@gmail.com ",
    " key_7 ": " gracemalulu@gmail.com ",
    " Nom_Agence ": " KIN 02 "
    " key_8 ": " 02 KIN ",
    " Libelle_Caisse ": "",
    " key_9 ": "",
    " Id_Agence ",
    " 2",
    " key_10 ",
    " 2",
    " role_id ",
    " 2",
    " key_11 "
    " 2",
    " Id_Caisse ": " ",
    " key_12 ": "",
    "Password ": " 7f59e02e7deaa6a33004b25a86024dee ",
    " key_13 ": " 7f59e02e7deaa6a33004b25a86024dee ",
    " Username": " gmalulu ",
    " key_14 ": " gmalulu "
    " Active ": " 1",
    " key_15 ": " 1 "
}, {
    " Id", " 2", " key_0 ", " 2", " Nom_Agent "
    " Vasco ", " key_1 "
    " Vasco ", " PNom_Agent "
    " Kabangu "
    " key_2 "
    " Kabangu ", " Sexe_Agent ", " M ", " key_3 ", " M ", " Adresse_Agent "
    " iSC ", " key_4 "
    " iSC ", " Telephone_Agent ": " 243 ",
    " key_5 ": " 243 ",
    " Libelle_Role ": " Agency head ",
    " key_6 ": " Agency head ",
    " Email_Agent ": " vkabungu @ ",
    " key_7 ": " vkabungu @ ",
    " Nom_Agence ": " KIN 02 ",
    " key_8 ": " KIN 02 ",
    " Libelle_Caisse ": " ",
    " key_9 ": " ",
    " Id_Agence ",
    " 2 ",
    " key_10 ",
    " 2 ",
    " role_id ",
    " 3 ",
    " key_11 ",
    " 3 ",
    " Id_Caisse ": " ",
    " key_12 ": " ",
    " Password ": " 325a2cc052914ceeb8c19016c091d2ac ",
    " key_13 ": " 325a2cc052914ceeb8c19016c091d2ac ",
    " Username ": " vkabungu ",
    " key_14 ": " vkabungu ",
    " Active ": " 1 ",
    " key_15 "
    " 1 "
}, {
    " Id", " 1", " key_0 ": " 1",
    " Nom_Agent "
    " Lepeya "
    " key_1 "
    " Lepeya "
    " PNom_Agent "
    " Otoko "
    " key_2 "
    " Otoko ",
    " Sexe_Agent ",
    " M ",
    " key_3 ",
    " M ",
    " Adresse_Agent "
    " lol122 Mombele "
    " key_4 "
    " lol122 Mombele "
    " Telephone_Agent ": " 213 ",
    " key_5 ": " 213 "
    " Libelle_Role ": " Cashier ",
    " key_6 ": " Cashier ",
    " Email_Agent ": " lepeyaherve@agb.cd ",
    " key_7 ": " lepeyaherve@agb.cd ",
    " Nom_Agence ": " KIN 02 "
    " key_8 ": " 02 KIN ",
    " Libelle_Caisse "
    " Case 01 ",
    " key_9 "
    " Case 01 ",
    " Id_Agence ",
    " 2",
    " key_10 ",
    " 2",
    " role_id "
    " 2"
    " key_11 ": " 2",
    " Id_Caisse ": " 2",
    " key_12 ": " 2",
    " Password ": " 325a2cc052914ceeb8c19016c091d2ac ",
    " key_13 ": " 325a2cc052914ceeb8c19016c091d2ac ",
    " Username": " lherve "
    " key_14 ": " lherve ",
    " Active ": " 0 ",
    " key_15 ": " 0 "
}]
```

the script knockout:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function Agent(data) {
    this.id=data.id;
    this.Nom_Agent=data.Nom_Agent;
    this.PNom_Agent=data.PNom_Agent;
    this.Sexe_Agent=data.Sexe_Agent;
    this.Adresse_Agent=data.Adresse_Agent;
    this.Telephone_Agent=data.Telephone_Agent;
    this.Libelle_Role=data.Libelle_Role;
    this.Email_Agent=data.Email_Agent;
    this.Nom_Agence=data.Nom_Agence;
    this.Username=data.Username;
    this.Id_Role=data.Id_Role;
    this.Id_Caisse=data.Id_Caisse;
    this.Date_Affectation=data.Date_Affectation;
    this.Libelle_Caisse=data.Libelle_Caisse;
    this.Id_Lieu=data.Id_Lieu;
    this.Active=ko.observable(data.Active)
}

function AgentListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.agents= ko.observableArray([]);
    $.ajax("/agence/allagent", {
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) {     
              var mappedAgents = $.map( result, function(item) {
                   return new Agent(item) ; });
        self.agents(mappedAgents);
    });

}

ko.applyBindings(new AgentListViewModel());

</script>
```

please help me

Comment: Something appears to have scrambled your code during the cut-and-paste process: most of the code you have isn't valid JavaScript and it's difficult to tell what you intended.

Comment: json data is also invalid.

Comment: please could you tell me what wrong with the json , i used json_encode ()  and data is rertieve with custom class

Answer (score 0):

you can set the observable array using the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

```
AgentListViewModel function ( ) {
var self = this;
self.agents ko.observableArray = ( [ ] ) ;

$.ajax ("/branch/allagent" {
    contentType : "application/json "
    success : function ( result) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self.agents) };
     }
  });
}
```

I set up a fiddle with an example of how you can use it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gNJN5/409/)